# Semantic Comparison between Sentence

Tags: nlp, semantic-web, sentence, sentence-similarity, lsa

I want to do a semantic comparison of sentences. For example, I have an input:

> "Trump has never been the president of the United States"

I do web-scraping against this on newspapers and found, let suppose this result:

> "Trump is the president of the United States".

Now I need to do a semantic comparison of the input and result(multiple) to identify whether the given input was correct or not.

I have surfed the internet and found some API's like [dandelion](https://dandelion.eu/semantic-text/text-similarity-demo/) and [paralleldots](http://paralleldots.com/semantic-analysis), but they are doing sentence comparison and give me **above 90%** score for this.

Can anyone guide me on how to overhaul this issue or any Open Source API that I can use for this task?

Another example:

Input:

> "Trump is the president of the United Kingdom"

Comparing Input with:

> "Trump is the president of the United States"